# vim-plug's "PlugInstall" not an editor command

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin

I tried many solutions suggested by the internet but none worked, propably i´m missing some point.

I have two folder related to neovim in my windows, one in my pc:

C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\nvim -> this is where i have the init.vim file and the autoload then plugged folders.

And this one in my program files
C:\Program Files\Neovim -> with these three folder in it, bin, lib and share.

As suggested by this tutorial : https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug

I´m entering to this adress :  C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\nvim\autoload

and running this command :

iwr -useb https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim |`
ni $HOME/vimfiles/autoload/plug.vim -Force

But my terminal only returns this and nothing more.

Diretório: C:\Users\WIN\vimfiles\autoload

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name

---

-a----        24/08/2023     11:51          83127 plug.vim

I tried many youtube videos and what i noticed is propably some error in the address or something.
I tried these two aproaches inside the init.vim file

call plug#begin'C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\nvim\autoload\plugged'
Plug 'sainnhe/sonokai'
call plug#end()

and

call plug#begin()
Plug 'sainnhe/sonokai'
call plug#end()